# I am stumped - receiving an IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch using DataProvider TestNG

Tags: java, excel, testing, selenium

Ok I am a little confused and stumped.  I am using a TestNG's Dataprovider to load in data from an excel file.  I created two DataProviders as follows and put them in a util:

```
@DataProvider(name = "OrderEdit")
public static Object[][] orderEdit() throws BiffException, IOException {
    return LoadTestData.getData("OrderEdit");
}

@DataProvider(name = "OrderCreate")
public static Object[][] orderCreate() throws BiffException, IOException{
    return LoadTestData.getData("OrderCreate");
}
```

The ("") passed in represents the sheet name of the excel file.  Loading the data from the excel file is fine and gets the correct results.

I created a test class to test the providers and if I have one test it runs fine with one provider. If I have two tests, the first test will run fine but the second will get the "IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch." I am passing in the correct amount of parameters (correct parameters in the excel file and the correct parameters passed in to the method).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The test code is as follows:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "OrderEdit", dataProviderClass = DataUtils.class)
public void test1(String user, String env, String searchBy, String button, String section){
    DriverFactory df = new DriverFactory(getDriver());
    OrderSummaryPageEnum option = OrderSummaryPageEnum.valueOf(button);

    df.commonUtils.navigateToURL(_targetURL);
    df.loginPage.login(user);
    df.orderSearchPage.navigateToOrderSearchPage();
    df.orderSearchPage.searchByOrderStatus(env, searchBy);
    df.orderSearchPage.selectConfirmationNumber();
    df.orderSummaryPage.selectRefundOption(option);
    df.orderEditCreatePage.selectSectionToEdit(section);
    List<String> productList = df.orderEditCreatePage.getProducts();
    df.orderEditPage.clickReviewButton();
    df.orderConfirmChangesPage.confirm();
    //df.orderConfirmChangesPage.verifyCorrectTotalAmount(productList);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "OrderCreate", dataProviderClass = DataUtils.class)
public void test_verifyNewOrderCreated(UsersEnum user, String productType, String product, String sku, boolean isStandardOrder,
                                       boolean isComplimentary, boolean isShippingFree,
                                       boolean isTaxState, boolean isShippingSame, String shippingCountry){
    DriverFactory df = new DriverFactory(getDriver());


    df.commonUtils.navigateToURL(_targetURL);
    df.loginPage.adminLogin(user);
    df.serviceHomePage.navigateToServiceHomePage();
    df.serviceHomePage.startNewOrder(productType, product, sku, isStandardOrder);
    df.orderEditCreatePage.createNewOrder(productType, isStandardOrder, isComplimentary, isShippingFree, isTaxState, isShippingSame, shippingCountry);
    String confirmNumberCreatePage = df.orderEditCreatePage.getConfirmationNumber();
    df.orderCreatePage.review();
    df.orderConfirmChangesPage.confirm();
    String confirmNumberInfoPage = df.orderSummaryPage.getConfirmationNumber();
    assertTrue(df.orderSummaryPage.changesSavedMessage());
    assertTrue(confirmNumberInfoPage.contains(confirmNumberCreatePage));
}
```

Thank you

EDITED...

Adding the code that is used to retrieve the data - got the code template from here (forgot which post but I am looking for it now to reference it here)

```
public static Object[][] getData(String sheetName)throws BiffException, IOException{
    Sheet sheet = null;
    try{
        sheet = getWorkBook().getSheet(sheetName);
        endRow = sheet.getRows();
        endCol = sheet.getColumns();
        contents = new String[endRow-1][endCol-1];
        int ci;
        int cj;
        ci=0;
        for(int i=1; i<endRow; i++, ci++){
            cj=0;
            for(int j=1; j<endCol; j++, cj++){
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j,i);
                if(cell.getContents().isEmpty()){
                    continue;
                }
                contents[ci][cj] = cell.getContents();
                //System.out.print(String.format("%s", contents[ci][cj]));
            }
        }
        System.out.print(String.format("%s", contents));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. My guess is that the function LoadTestData.getData(...) is returning an Object[][] that's not correctly formatted. We need some details about how this function creates that Object[][], could you provide that please?

Comment: Just added the code...

Comment: I actually figured out the answer. I realized that I was returning the contents of type string when loading from my excel file and then trying to pass it to type boolean in my test.  All fixed now!